# How to restore SVN after IDEA crash during commit?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

During a commit to the SVN server, my IDEA was forcibly killed by the OS (Ubuntu got frozen and I had to restart the system). After the restart, I got a task-bar message like `SVN changes update error` or something like that. I noticed this error at the very end and it disappeared after a few seconds.

After that I lost all SVN icons. I cannot either update or commit to SVN.

How do I restore this so that IDEA can again recognize the `.svn` folder in my sources?

I can only guess that some lock file remained undeleted but I was not able to find and delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that IDEA in case of error in some Version control system simply disables the add-on in question.

To re-enable it, simply open IDEA main screen, go to Configure -> Plugins, search for Subversion (or any other vcs) and re-enable it.

After IDEA restarts, the VCS will be active again.